# Selecting subsets with size $\frac{n}{2}$ covering every pair of the elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a set $S$ of $n$ elements. Let $T$ be the set of all subsets of $S$, with size $\frac{n}{2}$ ($n$ is even). We want to select a subset $T'$ of $T$, with the property that for any pair of the elements $x,y \in S$, there exists a subset $Q \in T'$, such that $x \in Q$ and $y \in Q$. What is the minimum size of $T'$? In particular, is $|T'| < n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is $6$ for $n \ge 4$. This is problem 1.3 on IMC 2013:

http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2013/IMC2013-day1-solutions.pdf

---

It takes $6$ subsets.

Lower bound: For any element $a$, to cover all $n-1 \gt 2(n/2 -1)$ pairs of elements including $a$, there must be at least $3$ subsets containing $a$. This is true for all elements so there must be at least $3n$ pairs $(e,Q), e\in Q$. Each subset contributes $n/2$ pairs $(e,Q), e \in Q$ so there must be at least $6$.

Construction: Write $n/2$ as $2s+3t$ with $s,t$ nonnegative integers. Break the elements into sets $A,B,C,D$ of size $s$ and $X',X'',Y',Y'',Z',Z''$ of size $t$, with $X= X' \cup X'', Y=Y'\cup Y'',Z = Z' \cup Z''$. Then consider the unions of $\{A,B,X,Y'\},$ $\{C,D,X,Y''\},$ $\{A,C,Y,Z'\},$ $\{B,D,Y,Z''\},$ $\{A,D,Z,X'\},$ and $\{B,C,Z,X''\}.$

Answer (score 7):

If $n$ is a power of two (i.e. if $n=2^m$), you can do quite a bit better-- you can take $|T'|=O(\log(n))$.

Interpret the elements of $S$ as $m$-bit binary strings.  Let $U_i^0$ be the set of elements for which the $i$-th bit is zero, and $U_i^1$ be the set of elements for which the $i$-th bit is one.  This separates $S$ in half, so $|U_i|=n/2$.  Let $\overline{x}$ be the bitwise complement of $x$ (i.e. we switch all the zeroes to ones and ones to zeroes in the binary string).

If $y\neq \overline{x}$, then there exists some $i$ such that the $i$-th bit of $x$ and $y$ are equal.  Suppose the $i$-th bit is $b$.  In that case, $x,y\in U_i^b$.

So, we just need to deal with the case where $x=\overline{y}$.  Take all the (disjoint) $n/2$ pairs of the form $(x,\overline{x})$.  Choose half (i.e. $n/4$) of these pairs, take the union, and call that set $V^0$; call the complement $V^1$.  Then if $y=\overline{x}$, either $(x,y)$ is in $V^0$ or $V^1$.

This achieves your condition with $2m+2=O(\log(n))$ sets.

Comment: Thanks @Bill . Your construction  shows that $O(\log n)$ sets are enough.

Answer (score 6):

It takes at least $5$ and at most $7$ subsets of size $n/2$ to cover every pair, for $n \ge 4$.

Since ${n/2 \choose 2} \lt {n \choose 2}/4$ for $n \ge 4$, at least $5$ are necessary.

If $n$ is divisible by $4$, you can do this with $6$ subsets. Divide the set into subsets of equal sizes, $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$. Then take $\lbrace S_i \cup S_j \rbrace$ with $i \ne j$. This is the best possible for $n=4$, and I think it is the best possible for larger $n$ divisible by $4$.

If $n$ is not divisible by $4$, you can cover all pairs with $7$ subsets.  Divide the set into disjoint subsets $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ of size $|S_i|=(n-2)/4$.  There will be two "extra" elements; let us call them $a$ and $b$. Then take $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \{a\}$, $S_3 \cup S_4 \cup \{a\}$, $S_1 \cup S_3 \cup \{b\}$, $S_2 \cup S_4 \cup \{b\}$. Then augment $S_1 \cup S_4$ and $S_2 \cup S_3$ by any one element each, and augment $\{a,b\}$ by any $n/2 - 2$ elements.

Usually, when people look at covering designs, the sizes of the blocks are much smaller than $n/2$.

In case you want to separate every pair of elements, then you need $\Theta(\log n)$ subsets.

Comment: Boy this is a lot better than my answer.  Why do we need $\Theta(\log n)$ subsets?  It seems like your construction would extend to $n = 2 \bmod 4$ with 9 sets or so.

Comment: Right, to cover every pair, $O(1)$ subsets suffice. To separate every pair, there need to be $\Theta(n)$, and I think that's what your construction was trying to do.

Comment: Ah, I see.  For completeness, I added the "not divisible by 4" case.

Comment: Oops, in my previous comment, I meant $\Theta(\log n)$ not $\Theta(n)$..

Comment: Fedor Petrov's answer includes a link to a complete solution. That is better than what I have here.

Comment: @Douglas: Thanks a lot. I didn't heard about "covering design". Is there a good resource about this topic?

Comment: There are a lot of resources available. For some parameters, the La Jolla Covering Repository is a great resource: https://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html. That doesn't have much theory, though. There are some basic inequalities which might be mentioned at the starts of most papers on covering designs.

Comment: It is also known under the notion "orthogonal arrays" and "covering arrays". There is a book by Hedayat, Sloane, and Stufken: "Orthogonal arrays, theory and applications" and a website by Neil Sloane http://neilsloane.com/doc/cent4.html . On orthogonal and covering arrays and their usage in software testing there exists a NIST website: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/acts/index.html. For a paper on covering arrays, where many problems and algorithms are discussed see e.g. https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/verification/mdt/papers/AlgorithmsForCoveringArraysPublication191203.pdf.

Comment: @Johannes Trost: Are you sure this is the same idea as an orthogonal array? That seems to require that there are subsets that contain each pair, don't contain each pair, contain the first but not the second, and contain the second but not the first equally often. That requires many more subsets.

Comment: @Douglas Zare You are right. The PO asks neither for orthogonal arrays, nor for covering arrays in the usual sense. Thank you, for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment:

Consider a bipartite graphs, with the subsets of size $n/2$ as vertices on the left, and pairs of elements on the right. An edge goes from a subset $S_i$ to a pair, if that pair is a subset of $S_i$.

Add axillary vertices $A$, connected to all subsets, and $Z$, connected to all pair vertices. Set weight $1$ on all edges from the pairs to $Z$, and weight $\infty$ on all other verices. Something that satisfies your condition is a maximal flow from $A$ to $Z$.

Perhaps it is possible to encode minimality on the number of subsets into this formulation...